# Why does this sentence have wrong subject-verb agreement?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement

Why is the error in this sentence a lack of subject-verb agreement?

> Sarah have a red car?

Comment: Is the phrase "Sarah have a car?" supposed to be a question or an exclamation? As in: "Sarah has a *red* car?" or *"Sarah has a red car!"* Is the phrase supposed to be an offer as in "Sarah, have a red car!". Please clarify the meaning you want to convey.

Answer (score 2):

The verb "to have" conjugates as:

Singular
 - I have
 - You have 
 - He/She/It has

Sarah is neither First (I) or Second (You) person.  Sarah is third person. So the sentence is

> Sarah has a red car.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wanted to formulate a question. Why else is the question mark added? The OP's post is generally unclear and unhelpful.